# how to populate two diffrent html tables inside php while loop depending on condition?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

i want to fill two different html tables inside php while loop .My current code populate table 1 when name is not empty(**$row[name]**) . However , how i can declare table2 so it only populate table2 when name is empty ? could any one show me how i can declare 2 different tables and fill both them depending if name value from db is empty or not ?

```
//table declration
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>page URL</th>
<th>img URL</th>
</tr>";


foreach ($lines as $line) {

//print_r( $line );

$line = rtrim($line);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID,name,imgUrl,imgPURL FROM testdb WHERE imgUrl like '%$line'");            


 if (!$result) {
             die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            }
//echo $result;


if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>1)
  {
    echo "<br>Duplicate in DB:".$line."<br>";
  };

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $totalRows++;



    if (!empty($row[name])) 
    {


      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] ."(".$totalRows. ")</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['imgPURL'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['imgUrl'] . "</td>";  echo "</tr>";


    } 
    else 
    { 
       $emptyNameCounter++;


        //fill table2 if name is empty



    };



}; // end of while loop


}
else
{
   echo "<br>Not Found:".$line."<br>";

}; 

};// end of for each line loop

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other way is append your data in varables for both table one and two and after the loop put the data in tables

here is a demo how you can do that

```
$table1='';
$table2='';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $totalRows++;
    if (!empty($row[name])) 
    {
      $table1.="<tr>";
      $table1.="<td>" . $row['ID'] ."(".$totalRows. ")</td>";
      $table1.="<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
      $table1.="<td>" . $row['imgPURL'] . "</td>";
      $table1.="<td>" . $row['imgUrl'] . "</td>";  echo "</tr>";

    } 
    else 
    { 
       $emptyNameCounter++;
     $table2.="data to show in table 2";
     //fill table2 if name is empty
    }
} // end of while loop

if(!empty($table1)){
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>page URL</th>
<th>img URL</th>
</tr>";
echo $table1;
echo "</table>";
}

if(!empty($table2)){
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>page URL</th>
<th>img URL</th>
</tr>";
echo $table2;
echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: thanks all. dianuj thanks your solution was very good . i didnt know i could append table data in variable!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to collect the data in an array first, then loop over that array twice.

There are other variations on that theme, but basically they're all about splitting the reading from the database and the rendering into two distinct steps.

Basically something like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) $rows[] = $result;

foreach( $rows as $row ) {
  // Render table 1
}

foreach( $rows as $row ) {
  // Render table 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than echo the tables out, store each table to a variable.  Once the loop is finished, echo out the variables.  Example

```
$tableOne = "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>page URL</th>
        <th>img URL</th>
    </tr>";
$tableTwo = "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>page URL</th>
        <th>img URL</th>
    </tr>";

//Code and Query here

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $totalRows++;

  if (!empty($row[name])) {
    $tableOne .= "<tr>";
    $tableOne .=  "<td>" . $row['ID'] ."(".$totalRows. ")</td>";
    $tableOne .= "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    $tableOne .= "<td>" . $row['imgPURL'] . "</td>";
    $tableOne .= "<td>" . $row['imgUrl'] . "</td>";  echo "</tr>";
  } 
  else { 
    $emptyNameCounter++; 
    //store in $tableTwo if name is empty
  }
}

//close tables, echo out variables
```